# DateEditor for util.Date in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, java.util.date

I want to create a CRUD-Application and my Problem is that i dont know how i could write a DateEditor for a JTable.

I do not have any idea how to implement a DateEditor. The Format should be "dd.mm.yyyy".

I hope you can help me.

The following things have i developed and work.

TableModel

```
    public class SheepTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{    
    ArrayList<Sheep> data = new ArrayList();
    private String[] columnNames;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"); 

    public SheepTableModel() {

        data.add(new Sheep(1, "Test", new Date(2014, 6, 7), "ADSF", "sdfwe", new Date(2014, 8, 27), 1, new Date(2014, 8, 27), "Testnotiz"));
        data.add(new Sheep(1, "Test", new Date(2014, 6, 7), "ADSF", "sdfwe", new Date(2014, 8, 27), 1, new Date(2014, 8, 27), "Testnotiz"));
        data.add(new Sheep(1, "Test", new Date(2014, 6, 7), "ADSF", "sdfwe", new Date(2014, 8, 27), 1, new Date(2014, 8, 27), "Testnotiz"));

        columnNames = new String[]{"Nummer", "Ohrenmarkennummer", "Geburtsdatum", "Nummer Mutter", "Nummer Vater", "DKV Datum", "Anmerkungsnummer", "Anmerkungsdatum", "Notiz"};
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Sheep s = (Sheep) data.get(rowIndex);
        switch(columnIndex){
            case 0: return s.getSheepnumber();
            case 1: return s.getEarnumber();
            case 2: return s.getBirthdate();
            case 3: return s.getNr_mum();
            case 4: return s.getNr_dad();
            case 5: return s.getDkvdate();
            case 6: return s.getNotenr();
            case 7: return s.getNote_date();
            case 8: return s.getNote_addtext();
            default: return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){ 
        return col != 0; 
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            switch(col){
                case 1: data.get(row).setEarnumber(((String) (value))); break;
                case 2: data.get(row).setBirthdate(((Date) (value)));break;
                case 3: data.get(row).setNr_mum(((String) (value)));break;
                case 4: data.get(row).setNr_dad(((String) (value)));break;
                case 5: data.get(row).setDkvdate(((Date) (value)));break;
                case 6: data.get(row).setNotenr(((Integer)(value)));break;
                case 7: data.get(row).setNote_date(((Date)(value)));break;
                case 8: data.get(row).setNote_addtext(((String) (value)));
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
        return columnNames[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex){
            case 0: return int.class;
            case 1: return String.class;
            case 2: return Date.class;
            case 3: return String.class;
            case 4: return String.class;
            case 5: return Date.class;
            case 6: return int.class;
            case 7: return Date.class;
            case 8: return String.class;
        }
        return Object.class;

    }

}
```

DateRenderer

```
    public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column );
        if ( value instanceof Date ){
            // Use SimpleDateFormat class to get a formatted String from Date object.
            String strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy").format((Date)value);
            // Sorting algorithm will work with model value. So you dont need to worry about the renderer's display value.
            this.setText( strDate );
    }

    return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: [JCalendar](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/) is an option?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things.

1. Create a renderer. Check out [Table Format Render](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easy way to do this. Note you can't just use `"dd.mm.yyyy"` for the format since upper/lower characters mean different things. Read the `SimpleDateFormat` API for the proper format characters to use.
2. You need to create a custom editor to edit the Date. I would guess you should be able to use the `DefaultCellEditor` with a `JFormattedTextField` that uses the appropriate mask. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information on JFormattedTextField.

The basic code might be something like:

```
MaskFormatter format = new MaskFormatter(...);
JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField( format );
DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( ftf );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(...).setCellEditor(dce);
```

The Swing tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Tables` which give more information on renders and editors.